# Wpf - How to make picture box full view

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen, picturebox

I am using picture box in my wpf application. The use of these picture box is to preview the video. So when the user click the full view button, how to make full screen the video(ie, picture box).?

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Black">
        <wf:PictureBox  BorderStyle="FixedSingle"   x:Name="pictureBox1"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

[image]

Comment: Uhm, is there a particular reason why you are using a *Windows Forms* PictureBox in your *WPF* application? There shouldn't really be a need for that ...

Comment: yes, i am using a third party control, that have win form..